# Синтаксис Python, срез строки

Tags: python

Что делает/означает символ в строке `a = slovo[::-1]`, а конкретней `::`?

```py
slovo = str(input())
a = slovo[::-1]
if slovo == a:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: Параметры среза https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данная запись означает срез в данном случае строки. Данная операция так же может быть применена к типам данных `list` и `tuple`.

#### Как это работает

Запись `obj[START:STOP:STEP]` означает, что из объекта с именем `obj` взять все члены последовательности от члена с индексом `START` (включая в последовательность) до члена с индексом `STOP` (не включая его в последовательность) с шагом `STEP`.

Все значения `START`, `STOP`, `STEP` имеют значения по умолчанию, т. е. значения могут не указываться и это будет значить

1. `START` = 0
2. `STOP` = всей длине объекта `obj`
3. `STEP` = 1

Учитывая вышесказанное, данная запись

`obj[::]`

будет читаться так: взять все члены последовательности между членом с индексом 0 (`START` = 0 по умолчанию) и членом с индексом равным длине последовательности (`STOP` = всей длине объекта `obj`) с шагом 1 (`STEP` = 1)

### Если же указать шаг с минусом

Каждый член последовательности имеет не только положительный индекс, но также и отрицательный. То есть последний элемент последовательности имеет индекс `-1`, предпоследний `-2` и т.д.

Тогда запись

`obj[::-1]`

будет означать: взять все члены последовательности между членом с индексом 0 (`START` = 0 по умолчанию) и членом с индексом равным длине последовательности (`STOP` = всей длине объекта `obj`) с шагом -1. То есть

1. 0-1 = -1, взять последний элемент
2. -1-1 = -2, взять предпоследний элемент
3. и т.д.

То есть буквально означает, *взять все элементы последовательности справа налево*

Answer (score 1):

`data = str[*1:*2:*3]`
*1 и *2 это срез то-есть с какого и до какого номера элемента работать
*3 так сказать шаг среза в вашем примере -1 означает что код пойдет с последнего до первого элемента в строке (то-есть букве)

Comment: Зря вы так обозначили `*1` и т.д., это только запутывает вместо чтобы сделать понятнее